# Error installing scipy using pip on Windows 10 32 bit

Tags: windows, python-2.7, scipy

Installing scipy using pip gives me following error.

Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\arun\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-nlwjdr\scipy\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\arun\appdata\local\temp\pip-5qc2vr-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\arun\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-nlwjdr\scipy\

Tried cloning the scipy from github and running setup command. No luck.

```
python setup.py install
```

UPDATE: Installed Windows binary available at this link and it worked
http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.11.0/scipy-0.11.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

Comment: Have you tried installing with [windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) ?

Comment: @tonyMontana yes, i tried below and it worked.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.11.0/scipy-0.11.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download